# Convert pandas series datetime return wrong format

Tags: python, pandas

I've this issue, when trying to convert this pandas series

```
x = pd.Series(["12/01/2017", "09/03/2018", "23/11/2019"])
```

The expected result should be :

```
0   2017-01-12
1   2018-03-09
2   2019-11-23  
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

When I run :

```
pd.to_datetime(x, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

I get

```
0   2017-12-01  >> Wrong Inverted day with month
1   2018-09-03  >> Wrong Inverted day with month
2   2019-11-23
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: `new_x = pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. The dates were parsed incorrectly from the start. Use `dayfirst=True` to tell Pandas that the first value is the day. `yearfirst=False` is the default, specifying it has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
pd.to_datetime(x, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y').astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: There's no reason to assume that `.astype('datetime64[ns]')` will work any better than `to_datetime(x, yearfirst=False, errors='coerce')` in the US, or any country where the default date format isn't `DD/MM/YYYY`

Comment: .astype('datetime64[ns]') its to keep the format dtype: datetime64[ns]